# Did they use models or CGI for the spaceships in The Force Awakens?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, behind-the-scenes, special-effects, cgi

Before *The Force Awakens* was released, Lucasfilm talked a lot about their efforts to use practical effects and such, using CGI relatively sparingly.

[This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CTNJ51ghzdY) covers practical costumes, props, droids, aliens, and lifesize vehicles and ships for when the ships have landed but there's no mention of how the ships were done **for space battles**.

The original trilogy [used](http://www.siggraph.org/sites/default/files/star-wars-ILM-empire-strikes-back-model-millennium-falcon.jpg) small [models](http://cdn-static.denofgeek.com/sites/denofgeek/files/styles/insert_main_wide_image/public/1/05//starwars1977-johndykstra-1100x720.jpg?itok=DwNJ77vY) for the [spaceships](http://theredlist.com/media/database/settings/cinema/1970-1980/star-wars/042-star-wars-theredlist.jpg) when doing the space battles:

[image]

[image]

[image]

## Did they use models for any of the spaceships in *The Force Awakens*?

Comment: Based on the absence of set photos, my guess is that the exteriors were almost entirely CGI.

Comment: I remember reading an article this week that epxlicitly noted TFA - despite the hype to the contrary - having MORE CGI and less models- than Episode I :)

Comment: Wouldn't this be a question for http://movies.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The spaceships and space battles for *The Force Awakens* **appear to be purely CGI.**

In these behind the scenes videos, none of the spaceships appear to be models like in the Original Trilogy. While these videos don't give a comprehensive look at *every* special effect in the film, they do seem to indicate that the spaceships were completely CGI in *The Force Awakens*.